# Can not set vissability on DIV element to true manually. "TH:IF" issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring, thymeleaf

I have the following DIV:

```
.. <div class="row" th:if="${error}" id="divError" name="divError">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" th:text="${error}" id="errorMessenge">An
                error occured</div>
      </div>
   </div> ...
```

Now I have the following SCRIPT:

```
function someFunction(){
.........................
   if(something){
      $("#errorMessenge").text("Error for example"); // <- works 
      //HERE I WANT TO SET THIS "TH:IF" ON ROW "divError" TO TRUE
      //SO THE ROW WITH THE "Error for example" WILL SHOW.
   }
}
```

I tried things like:

```
$("#divError").css("display", "");
$("#divError").css('visibility', 'visible');
$("#divError").css('display','block');
$("#divError").show();
```

Nothing works.
My question is: Is that div hidden or does not exists ? Because if it does not exists there is no point for me to trying make it "visible" and if that is so how can I work through it manually. When  ${error} attribute is added to the Module in the java controller it works just fine but when I want to set it on the fly it does not work.

Comment: i suppose at the server side it is decided that the element should be rendered within html or not.

Comment: Correct. On some cases I decide to add or not this element to the html at the server side, but  once NOT added in some circumstances in html (clicking a button for example) I want the "divError" to appear if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

To check whether an element exists or not, you can simply console.log the length of elements, like:

`console.log($("#divError").length);`

Or you can directly open the console in developer's tools and use

`$("#divError").length`

If length is greater than zero, element exists.